# App using Swift package with binary dependencies Builds but does not run

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I am wrapping the XCFramework of Google Places SDK for iOS as a Swift Package. Then I am trying to use this Swift Package in an iOS application.

Here is where I downloaded Google Places XCFramework: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/config#install-manually

Here is the Swift Package I created out of it:
https://github.com/dogahe/DogahePlaces

The iOS application that uses the Swift Package builds but does not run on the simulator. The error is

```
Unable To Install “UsePlaces”

Please try again later.
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/dogahe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C66A1B4F-91B0-4786-899A-ACF214F1920E/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ZzHcTC/extracted/UsePlaces.app/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework; Extra info about "/Users/dogahe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C66A1B4F-91B0-4786-899A-ACF214F1920E/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ZzHcTC/extracted/UsePlaces.app/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/dogahe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C66A1B4F-91B0-4786-899A-ACF214F1920E/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.ZzHcTC/extracted/UsePlaces.app/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
```

which is exactly the same error as if I followed the Google Places instructions from
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ios-sdk/config#install-the-xcframework

but did not switch the Embed settings of Google Places from "Embed & Sign" to "Do Not Embed". In other words, as it is instructed in the Google Places instructions if I choose "Do Not Embed" everything is fine but if I leave the Embed settings as "Embed & Sign" I get the same error as I get in my Swift Package version.

I want to figure out how to make the Swift Package version work. Since in the Swift Package there is no option for embedding or not embedding. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this issue?